# Using node fluent-ffmpeg for converting images to video

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I've found lots of samples for this but none of them was working properly for me.

I have a couple of Images. Either URLs, Base64s or Buffers.

I need to convert them to a video, without altering quality.

The closest I came was this command:
`ffmpeg -framerate 1 pattern_type glob -i 'images/*.jpg' -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`

But it showed 1 image per second. I need the video to be 30fps, not 1 image with 30 frames, but 30 images in a second.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a different package - [ffmpeg-stream](https://github.com/phaux/node-ffmpeg-stream)

I was getting the images from AWS, so there is some AWS code below:

```
const frames = ['frame1.jpg', 'frame2.jpg', ...]

const conv = ffmpeg() // create converter
const input = conv.input({f: 'image2pipe', r: 30}) // create input writable stream
conv.output('out.mp4', {vcodec: 'libx264', pix_fmt: 'yuv420p'}) // output to file

// for every frame create a function that returns a promise
frames.map(filename => () =>
  new Promise((fulfill, reject) =>
    s3
      .getObject({Bucket: '...', Key: filename})
      .createReadStream()
      .on('end', fulfill) // fulfill promise on frame end
      .on('error', reject) // reject promise on error
      .pipe(input, {end: false}) // pipe to converter, but don't end the input yet
  )
)
// reduce into a single promise, run sequentially
.reduce((prev, next) => prev.then(next), Promise.resolve())
// end converter input
.then(() => input.end())

conv.run()
```

Here's the issue I had posted on the github repo:
https://github.com/phaux/node-ffmpeg-stream/issues/5